# Expected variance of $N$ random variables chosen from a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, variance, uniform-distribution

Consider the uniform distribution on $[a, b]$. There are $N$ random variables $X_1, X_2, ... , X_N$ chosen from that distribution. How can we determine the expected variance of the $N$ random variables?

I'm not sure if that's the proper terminology, so I'll explicitly mention the value I'm looking for. Let
$$Y = \frac{1}{N} (X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_N)$$
I want to determine
$$E\left[\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^N (Y - X_i)^2\right]$$

Here's my progress so far
\begin{align*} &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^N \left( E[Y^2] + E[X_i^2] - 2E[X_i Y] \right)\\
&= E[Y^2] + E[X_i^2] - 2E[X_i Y]\\
&= E[Y^2] + E[X_i^2] - 2 \frac{N - 1}{N} E[X_i]^2 - 2\frac{1}{N} E[X_i^2]\\
&= E[Y^2] + (1 - \frac{2}{N}) \int_a^b x^2 dx - \frac{2(N - 1)}{N} \left(\frac{a + b}{2} \right)^2\\
&= E[Y^2] + \left(1 - \frac{2}{N}\right) \left( \frac{b^3 - a^3}{3} \right) - \frac{2(N - 1)}{N} \left(\frac{a + b}{2} \right)^2\end{align*}

Is there a simpler way to evaluate $E[Y^2]$ instead of computing $Y^2$ and then applying expectation on each of the terms? Am I doing everything else right?

Comment: are the $X_i$ independent ?

Comment: Yes, $X_i$ are independent

Comment: Did you attempt a solution and get stuck somewhere? That information will be necessary for someone to help you.

Comment: Added my attempt!

Comment: OH wait. Is $E[Y^2] = \frac{1}{N} E[X_i^2] + \frac{N^2 - N}{N^2} E[X_i]^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path.  The key to the proof is to expand $Y$ as a sum and take the expectation term-by-term noting that
$$
E[X_iX_j]=
\begin{cases}
E[X_i^2], & i=j\\
E[X_i]E[X_j], & i\neq j.
\end{cases}
$$
A full proof of the fact
$$
E\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(Y-X_i)^2\right]=\frac{N-1}{N}Var[X]
$$
is found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Biased_sample_variance), which holds for any random variable with finite variance. Once you have convinced yourself of this fact, note that
$$
X=\frac{a+b}2{+X^\prime},
$$
where $X^\prime\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(-(b-a)/2,(b-a)/2)$. Thus
$$
Var[X]=Var\left[\frac{a+b}2{+X^\prime}\right]=Var[X^\prime].
$$
It follows that
$$
Var[X^\prime]=\int_{-(b-a)/2}^{(b-a)/2}\frac{x^2}{b-a}\,dx=\frac{((b-a)/2)^3}{3(b-a)}-\frac{(-(b-a)/2)^3}{3(b-a)}=\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}.
$$
So we have
$$
E\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(Y-X_i)^2\right]=\frac{N-1}{N}\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is written [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2771615/144421).  The $Y$ is replaced by
$\overline X$. The final result is

$$E\left[\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^N ( X_i-\overline X)^2\right]=\frac{1}{N} \cdot \sigma^2 \cdot (N-1),$$

where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of a uniform distributed variable $X_i\sim U(a,b)$. Thus the variance is

$$\sigma^2=Var(X_i)=E\left(X_i^2 \right)-[E(X_i)]^2=\int_a^b x^2\cdot \frac{1}{b-a} \ dx-\left[ \int_a^b x\cdot \frac{1}{b-a} \ dx\right]^2$$

$$=\frac13\cdot (a^2+ab+b^2)-\left( \frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2=\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can write, for each $i$,
$$
(Y-X_i)^2 = (Y-\mu)^2+(X_i-\mu)^2-2(Y-\mu)(X_i-\mu),\qquad (1)
$$
where $\mu=E[Y] = E[X_i] = (a+b)/2$. Writing $\sigma^2 = (b-a)^2/12$ for the variance of $X_i$, the mean of the expression in (1) is
$$
{\sigma^2\over N}+\sigma^2 -2E[(Y-\mu)(X_i-\mu)].
$$
Now sum over $i$ and divide by $N$ to get
$$E\left[\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^N (Y - X_i)^2\right]
={N+1\over N}\sigma^2-2E[(Y-\mu)(Y-\mu)]={N+1\over N}\sigma^2-2{\sigma^2\over N}
=(1-1/N)\sigma^2.
$$